# Javascript: managing clicks from one instance to the next

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, prototype, instance

I am very new to Javascript.

I am trying to write this baby jQuery plugin that I will use to make dropdown lists. What I am failing to achieve (beyond things that I do not notice) is to neatly exit or deactivate my active instance as I click on another instance. I tried to illustrate my problem in the following fiddle (keeping the structure I am using):
https://jsfiddle.net/andinse/m0kwfj9d/23/

What the Javascript looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $.fn.activator = function() {
    var Activator = function(el) {
      this.html = $('html');
      this.el = el;
      this.is_active = false;
      this.initialize();
    };

    Activator.prototype.initialize = function() {
      var self = this;
      self.el.on('click', function(e) {
        if (self.is_active === false) {
          self.toggle('activate');
        } else {
          self.toggle('deactivate');
        }
        });
    };

    Activator.prototype.toggle = function(action) {
      var self = this;
        if (action === 'activate') {
        console.log('activating ' + self.el[0].className);
                self.is_active = true;
        self.el.addClass('red');
                self.html.on('click', function(e) {
          if (e.target != self.el[0]) {
            self.toggle('deactivate');
          }
        });
      }
            if (action === 'deactivate') {
        console.log('deactivating ' + self.el[0].className);
        self.is_active = false;
        self.el.removeClass('red');
        self.html.off('click');
            }
    };

    if (typeof this !== 'undefined') {
      var activator = new Activator(this);
    }
    return this;
    };

  $('.a').activator();
  $('.b').activator();
  $('.c').activator();

});
```

My idea was:

- To watch for clicks on html as soon as the instance is active (thus ready to be deactivated). On click, to check if the event.target is the same as the active instance. If not, to deactivate this instance.
- To stop watching for clicks as soon as the instance is inactive. So that we're not doing unnecessary work.

When it is set like this, it seems to work for only one cycle (click on A activates A then click on B activates B and deactivates A then click on C activates C but doesn't deactivate B).

If I get rid of the "self.html.off('click')" it seems to work kind of ok but if I look at the log I can see the "toggle" function is sometimes triggered multiple times per click. There must be a cleaner way.

Any piece of help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

With your logic, when clicking any element you should deactivate any current activated element. Either do it globally:

```
$('.your_activation_class').removeClass('.your_activation_class');
```

or in some parent scope

```
$('some_parent_selector .your_activation_class').removeClass('.your_activation_class');
```